# Exporting Project from SSIS integration service. now same ispac file redeploy to integration service catalog validation fail

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

first i export project from ssisdb integration service, i got my .ispac file now i am try to redeploy same ispac file in integration service catalog it   is deploy . when i try to validate package after assigning environment validation test is fail

Regards,
Manish

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: error-There were errors during task validation

Regards,
manish